# Where can I find the stock kernel for my Samsung Galaxy S2?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, kernel

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 phone (GT-I9100). I installed clockworkmod, a custom kernel and rom (Resurrection Remix) earlier this year. One day I couldn't boot it anymore. I restored a backup of the stock rom still on my sd card. My phone worked fine again, except that my camera doesn't show me any image while running. I can take pictures and videos, but I'm blind while filming.
I'm presuming this is because I still have the custom kernel installed. I would like to get back to an official Samsung kernel compatible with my old stock rom.

1. Where can I find such a kernel?
2. How can I be sure that it is the right one for my ROM?
3. What steps must I take to ensure that I can at least get back to the current state if something goes wrong in the process?

This is my current setup:

Model:
GT-I9100

Android:
4.0.4

Band:
I9100XXLPX

Kernel
3.0.15-TH
codeworkx@cyanogenmod #2
SMP PREEMPT Sun Apr 29 10:50:29 CEST
2012

Version:
IMM76D.BULPG

I appreciate any help you can give me on this topic.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this site?
[sammobile](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/1/?model=GT-I9100&pcode=CNX#firmware)
Just select the right country and mobile operator.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find the stock kernel for this device. Instead, I tried Siyah 5.0.1 http://www.gokhanmoral.com/?p=1536. I flashed it with Odin. Camera works! Will see if rest of phone still works as before.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an original kernel on Sam Mobile as @Sil suggested. I am using an original Orange ROM for my Samsung Galaxy S2. This website has original ROMs for all Samsung smartphones so I guess you just have to trust them, being one of the most used websites for this kind of content. About the installation, if it fails, which it shouldn't, you can just try installing the ROM again and if it still fails then you can re-install your current ROM. You can try backing up your settings files using [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup).